# Look for duplicate values across multiple columns ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following table structure

```
Columns: ID, FKID, NAME, TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3
```

I am trying to write a SQL script in ORACLE to count the duplicate records by ID. This is simple enough if TYPE1 is the same everywhere, but the duplicate values could be in TYPE1, TYPE2, or TYPE3 - so for example the following two rows should return as a duplicate row:

```
ID: 1, FKID: 1, NAME: Example1, TYPE1: 01, TYPE2: 02, TYPE3: 03
ID: 1, FKID: 1, NAME: Example2, TYPE1: 02, TYPE2: 03, TYPE3: 01
```

Comment: If TYPE1 is not the same in two different rows, then must the TYPE1, TYPE2, and TYPE3 all have matching values in the 2nd row or is it sufficient for just one of them to match with the 2nd row to be qualified as a duplicate rows?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
WHERE ID IN (
             SELECT ID FROM
                           (
                           SELECT ID
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3) as seqNum
                           FROM tableName
                           ) Z

             WHERE seqNum>1
            )
```

**Explanation**

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY  TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3)` will generate different sequence number **seqNum** for row if any of the column TYPE1, TYPE2 or TYPE3 has different value.

Answer (score 0):

The following query performs a self-join and matches TYPE1, TYPE2, and TYPE3 with either TYPE1, TYPE2, and TYPE3 of other rows. If there's a match, then the row is selected and finally, the count of rows per ID is obtained by grouping.

```
SELECT mt1.ID, COUNT(mt1.ID)
    FROM mytable mt1 
    INNER JOIN mytable mt2
    ON mt1.ID = mt2.ID AND (mt1.TYPE1 = mt2.TYPE1 OR mt1.TYPE1 = mt2.TYPE2 OR mt1.TYPE1 = mt2.TYPE3 OR mt1.TYPE2 = mt2.TYPE2 OR mt1.TYPE2 = mt2.TYPE3 OR mt1.TYPE3 = mt2.TYPE3)
    AND mt1.NAME <> mt2.NAME
    GROUP BY mt1.ID;
```